# Ng-view with Controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I am trying to concat the date given as input and the URL to get the JSON data from it. For ex; I have URL: http://url/date=2015-08-22, So this data from URL will give different values for different dates. Now, I want to display the data based on date selected and to display it in a single page(without refreshing page). Also I want to display data from this URL in a table.

Here is what I have as of right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/date', {
            templateUrl: 'table.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.info = {
        sel: " "
    };
    $http.get("http://192.168.2.1/info/posts?seldate=" + $scope.info.sel)
    .success(function (response) {
    $scope.condition = response.Table1
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
<body>    
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
        Date: <input type="text" ng-model="info.sel">
    </div>
     <div>
        <a href="#/date"><input type="button" value="Submit" /></a>    
     </div>
<div ng-view>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here Table1 is from URL and it has JSON data. Below is table.html, which I have used in code above:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Qualification</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in condition">
            <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Designation}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Qualification}}</td>           
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, the problem is when I enter the date and click on submit, I could only see the table headers and no content in it. I also made sure that there is no problem with URL and is working perfectly. Please provide solution for this. I really need this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should post some static json so we can see what exact data you are using and what input for the date you are using.

Comment: Take care you have 2 different versions of angular loaded via cdn.

Comment: cause your date is empty look at this   $scope.info = {
        sel: " "
    };

Comment: No info.sel is updated through <input type="text" ng-model="info.sel">

Comment: Hi @Pranitha, Actually what you try to achieve? When click on the submit button you want to get data from server and populate it in table?

Comment: @Pranitha, ok. First you want to handle your click of button. In that, you can fetch data and set it to **$scope.condition**. After that you want to redirect your view to **#/date**.

Comment: @Pranitha ok. Please come to this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/91049/ng-view-with-controllers?tab=general

Comment: @Pranitha. You can click on the link above. And there is a button "join this room" to start chat.

Comment: @AbhilashPA: I dont have the required reputation to join

Comment: @Pranitha. hmm :(. Chat was good.

Comment: @Pranitha, we can chat using this option (comment)

Comment: @Pranitha. Or I can create a long answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to use latest version of angularJS for your work.

So, we can change your script link to the following.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Here you can see that, we replace your angularJS v1.1 with two files called angular.min.js and angular-route.js. It is because, currently angular split angular library into different files.

Next change in your code is to inject **ngRoute** into your module. It is because of now, we use a new module for routing.

```
var app1 = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Your controller should look like :

```
app1.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.info = {
            sel: " "
        };

        $scope.subt_click = function () {
            $http.get("http://192.168.2.1/info/posts?seldate=" + $scope.info.sel)
                .then(function success(response) {
                    // Your success callback
                    $scope.condition = response.Table1
                },
                    function error() {
                        // Error callback
                    }
                );
            // populate your ng-view with table
            $location.path('/date');
        };

    });
```

We need to call function **$scope.subt_click** when user click on the submit button. We can use **ng-click** directive to achieve this,

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="subt_click()" />
```

So, your entire page would look like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app1 = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
        app1.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/date', {
                templateUrl: 'table.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise(
                {
                    template : '<h1> Home </h1>'
                }
            )
        }]);
        app1.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
            $scope.info = {
                sel: " "
            };

            $scope.subt_click = function () {
                $http.get("http://192.168.2.1/info/posts?seldate=" + $scope.info.sel)
                    .then(function success(response) {
                        // Your success callback
                        $scope.condition = response.Table1
                    },
                        function error() {
                            // Error callback
                        }
                    );
                // populate your ng-view with table
                $location.path('/date');
            };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div>
            Date: <input type="text" ng-model="info.sel">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="subt_click()" />
        </div>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's all !!!

I didn't test this code. If you got any issue please feel free to ask.

Thanks. :)

Comment: k. Sorry. I think I misunderstood your question. When user write this url with date and user id, then he should redirect to this table view which must be populated with data from server?

Comment: User will select the date from input and based on that date the data from URL has to be viewed in a table. User will select only the date. This data from server will differ based on change in the dates.

Comment: @Pranitha Could you please replace response.Table1 with **response.data.Table1**. And check whether is there any call happens when you call $http.get().

Comment: @Pranitha, I just created an API and tested in my local machine now. It is working fine. Please provide a break point in your success and error functions of $http.get()

Comment: @Pranitha, Current work flow is, Enter your date in the input, click submit button, it will call your server action for getting data, it will rewrite your url to 'baseUrl + #/date' then in your success function it assign server data into your scope object **condition**. It will reflect in your view.

Comment: Dats great!! Its working now.. Thank you so much Abhilash..You are awesome..cheers..

Comment: @Pranitha, Thank you. :)

Comment: Hello.. for the above I have added a date picker from my template. I have added 'ng-model=info.sel' , am able to select the date but not getting data from server.This is the code:<div class="input-group date"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date"></div> and script is: $(document).ready(function () {$('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({todayBtn: "linked",keyboardNavigation: false,forceParse: false,calendarWeeks: true,autoclose: true,format: "yyyy/mm/dd" });  Hope u will help me.

Comment: @Pranitha, Hi Pranitha, Nice to see you again. Sorry for the late reply. I was bit busy yesterday. I think today I can spend some time for you. But not now. Sorry, I have some urgent work in office.

Comment: @Pranitha Why don't you use Bootsrtap-Angular-UI? It may fix your issue. [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

Comment: Thanx a lot for the reply.. I have even tried with Bootstrap date picker. The problem is it is sending time along with date. So I'm unable to get the data from server. I need to select a date and only date value has to be sent as url.

Comment: @Pranitha, Did you tried to format your date value? You can specifies your desired date format. **yyyy/MM/dd** is the correct format. But you are used **mm** in your format. Actually **m** indicates **minutes** and **M** indicates month.

Comment: Even then I couldn't get the result. The problem is; for example, when I select the date 2015-10-13, the date is being  "2015-10-13T18:30:00.000Z" instead of 2015-10-13

Comment: @Pranitha, Sorry, I didn't get your issue. Where are you getting correct date and where is bad date? I mean, do you get correct date in client side (Jquery/ angular) and bad date in server?

Comment: I have created the plunker link, could you please check it here;  http://plnkr.co/edit/l1B0NIA7PYAuaDkzP65d?p=preview , When I select the date, only the date has to be sent to url.

Comment: @Pranitha, please check your plunker now.

Comment: @Pranitha, Have you got what I changed? Just filtered your model **dt** with date filter and assign it in a new model **parameterDate**. Now you can use this model to send date.

Comment: I'm sorry I could see no change..:(

Comment: @Pranitha, Sorry. How can I save your plunker?

Comment: @Pranitha, check this link [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wxieKFj0Mzh8TQ2j0exY?p=preview)

Comment: @Pranitha Sorry, I could not select date when click on your textbox - in plunker.

Comment: Please check now..I need to display data from server in a table after selecting date from datepicker.

Comment: @Pranitha What is the name of your API function? And what are the parameters in your call?

Comment: @Pranitha, check this [Updated Version](http://plnkr.co/edit/fRP3160upVBuPLBBpMXG?p=info)

Comment: @Pranitha, is this you need? Please let me know.

Comment: This is displaying the url link but I need the data from that url to be displayed in a table

Comment: @Pranitha Yes, you can get data from that url. Did you see a `$http(){}` method. You can set data from server in it's success function.

Comment: Also the start date is being assigned to end date here. But I need to select both the start and end datesseparately.

Comment: @Pranitha, I just write a sample code. You can update that to what you think.

Comment: @Pranitha, No problem. You can always contact me if you need any help. I am always happy to help. Feel Free !!! I am your friend.

Comment: @Pranitha I am always ready. But do not expect answer for all your queries. I am just a beginner  :).

Comment: Hello, I have modified the code you provided. I want to know 2 things:1. where can I include tablehtml file(HtmlPage2.html in my code). 2: How can I get data from url. This is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bD7KRYG53YuguJ8FEzjN?p=preview

Comment: Hi @Pranitha, 1. Do you want to show HtmlPage.html always in Indiex? If yes, you can configure it in your `app.config()` section. Or you can use `state` instead of `route`. I prefer `state` to routing.

Comment: I have to display the data from server in table after clicking on submit button.

Comment: @Pranitha ok. You can just use `ng-show` attribute to show your table. `ng-show="isTableVisible"` and set the model `$scope.isTableVisible = false` while initializing your controller and set it as `true` when you get data from server.

Comment: P A: Hello Abhilash.. I have tried including app.config to configure my htmlpage but its not working.. how can I proceed. Your suggestion is most needed.

Comment: Hi @Pranitha, Nice to see you again !!! Sorry to say, but I didn't get your problem. What do you want to configure in `app.config` file?

Comment: Please let me know if u have solution for my question.. I need it

Comment: @Pranitha, I am really sorry to say that I am very busy in these days as my projects is going to live.

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend you to use [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which offers more flexibility for your routes and nested views.

I think the best would be to separate your logic in a dedicated controller per view, and use the route parameter to retrieve the right date.

For instance your route would look like:

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/date/:date', {      //this add a parameter to your route
        templateUrl: 'table.html',
        controller: 'DateViewCtrl'      //this defines the controller for this ng-view scope
    });
```

Then you split your logic in 2 controllers, the MainCtrl:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.info = {
        sel: " "
    };
}]);
```

and something like this for the DateViewCtrl:

```
app.controller('DateViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $scope.condition = [];
    $http.get("http://192.168.2.1/info/posts?seldate=" + $routeParams.date)
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.condition = response.Table1;
    });
}]);
```

Then update the link:

```
   <a ng-href="#/date/{{your-date}}"><input type="button" value="Submit" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the button is not bound to any event handler. Try

`<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click='loadData()'/>`

Remove the enclosing `a` tag.

In the controller add the `ladData` function

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.info = {
        sel: " "
    };
    $scope.loadData=function() {
       $http.get("http://192.168.2.1/info/posts?seldate=" + $scope.info.sel)
       .success(function (response) {
          $scope.condition = response.Table1
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The button is wrapped in a <a>